# Android KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException is not catched when setUserAuthenticationRequired(true) and setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(X)

Tags: android, exception, fingerprint

Hello Android developers,

I've got something strange in my app when I'm using the Fingerprint and the AndroidKeystoreProvider together.

Here is the case:

I create a KeyPair with KeyPairGenerator.
In the builder I have set `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` and `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10)`.

Into my fingerprint I have enrolled 3 fingers.

When I try next to init the Signature algorithm with `initSign(...)` the first time, **UserNotAuthenticatedException** is catched. That's fair. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/UserNotAuthenticatedException.html)

Then I enroll a new finger into my fingerprint.

So I expect than when I init the Signature algorithm, it should catch **KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException** as described into the Google documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException.html) but it is not the case. **UserNotAuthenticatedException** is always catched.

If I remove `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10)` things gonna work as expected. (**KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException** is well catched)

Did you know if there is a way to make both exceptions work with `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` and `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10)` ?

Thank you in advance,
Matt

Comment: Hi Matt, I am facing the same issue. Were you able to solve/find anything concrete?

Answer (score 2):

No, `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException` is not thrown when `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds` > -1

From the [setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProtection.Builder.html#setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(int)) docs:

`Parameters: seconds    int: duration in seconds or`**`-1 if user authentication must take place for every use of the key`**.

and from [setUserAuthenticationRequired](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProtection.Builder.html#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)):

`Additionally,`**`if the key requires that user authentication takes place for every use of the key,`** `it is also irreversibly invalidated once a new fingerprint is enrolled`

---

Update (26.11.2018)

`KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException` will not be thrown if `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds > -1`, because:

> Cryptographic operations involving **keys which are authorized to be
>   used for a duration of time** after a successful user authentication
>   event can only use secure lock screen authentication. These
>   cryptographic operations **will throw UserNotAuthenticatedException**
>   during initialization if the user needs to be authenticated to
>   proceed.

Source: [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProtection.Builder#setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProtection.Builder.html#setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(int))

Comment: `No, KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException is not thrown when setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds > -1` : 
How did you infer this ?

Comment: still, it doesn't convey that `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException will not be thrown if setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds > -1`