# Android keystore UserNotAuthenticatedException infinite loop

Tags: android, android-keystore

I am using AndroidKeystore in my app to store a secret key, which has

```
.setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)      
.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(30*60)
```

I generate and store the secret key when user signup. And then to consume the key, I

```
methodToConsumeSecretKey(){
....
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
keyStore.load(null);
KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry;
secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(getSecretKeyAlias(), null);
final SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();
final Cipher cipher = getCipherInstance();
byte[] iv = BaseEncoding.base64().decode(<stored iv>);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
}
```

The expected behaviour for this code is:

It'll throw `UserNotAuthenticatedException` when the user has not authenticated in last 30 minutes (the duration that I am passing to `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds`).
I am listening for that exception and when that's thrown, I ask to authenticate the user using:

```
Intent intent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("Unlock", null);
if (intent != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CONFIRM_DEVICE_CREDENTIALS);
}
```

and then `onActivityResult()`, if I receive `RESULT_OK`, I try to execute `methodToConsumeSecretKey()` again.

Now, it works in most cases. But I've observed for some of our customers, `methodToConsumeSecretKey()` repeatedly throws `UserNotAuthenticatedException` even if the user has authenticated successfully. So, they are kind of stuck into a loop where they keep authenticating and OS keeps throwing this exception. 
I haven't observed any pattern in the devices or android versions of these customers. These are the number of users per android version:

```
[{"version":"8.1.0","count":"8119"},{"version":"8.0.0","count":"3384"},{"version":"7.0","count":"2882"},
{"version":"9","count":"1645"},{"version":"6.0.1","count":"1281"},{"version":"6.0","count":"1063"},
{"version":"7.1.2","count":"931"},{"version":"7.1.1","count":"880"}]
```

.

Also, this is not happening for particular manufacturer. These users are on `Xiaomi`, `OnePlus`, `Lenovo`, `Motorola` in decreasing order of count. There are other manufacturers too.

I've gone through android issuetracker bugs like [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65578763) and [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37127115), and questions like :
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920995/infinite-loop-using-androidkeystore-authentication) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073096/android-keypermanentlyinvalidatedexception-is-not-catched-when-setuserauthentica).

But still, haven't been able to arrive at a conlusion what might be causing this. 
One guess is that it's throwing `UserNotAuthenticatedException` in cases where it should throw  `keypermanentlyinvalidatedexception` (as stated in the second question and first bug linked above), but still not sure of that.

P.S. I've personally faced this issue in one of our test devices. I couldn't 
figure out why it was happening. I removed the device lock from the settings and set it again. After that, the issue was gone.

Comment: How did you make the fix? What actions stop this behavior? Only resetting phone screen lock, or we can just clear app data, cache or permissions?

Comment: Clearing app data, cache or permissions won't help as this is an OS level issue. resetting phone lock "might" help in some cases. that's also random. I haven't solved it yet. One approach is using a backup password approach, as in google samples

Comment: I experienced this issue on phone Samsung Galaxy J3 with Android 8.0

Comment: I've created a bug on issuetracker for this. You can track (and upvote if you want to put more pressure on them :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly feel this is a bug in android os and have created an issue for this here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119944680.

Please star the issue if you are facing this.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally faced this issue in one of my test devices (OnePlus).

I removed the device lock from the settings and set it again. After that, the issue was gone.

Comment: If you are facing this in production, please star the issue that I've mentioned in other answer.